# Unfold columns on masonry layout when there is space on the right

Tags: css, masonry

Having this example https://jsfiddle.net/20o1stn6/2/ is it possible that if there is enough space on the right show the items one by one and not one under another.

I tried changing the display value but not manage to have the full boxes align.

My layout has a left sidebar and when the sidebar is opened I should see 3 columns on the right, and when it is closed show 4 columns with responsive widths

I tried with flex

```
.masonry-with-columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-height: 1000px;
     div {
       width: calc(100% - 42px);
       margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
       display: inline-block;
       flex: 1 0 auto;
       margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
     }
   }
```

And also using the columns prop

```
 .masonry-with-columns {
   -moz-column-count: 3;
   -webkit-column-count: 3;
   column-count: 3;
   columns: 411px;
  }
```

Both having the same problem, showing items one under another even if there is enough space on the right

Answer (score 0):

Example with equal width divs wich are increasing from 150px if space is there

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.masonry-with-columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.masonry-with-columns div {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 150px;
  background: #EC985A;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(1) {
  height: 241px;
  line-height: 241px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(2) {
  height: 109px;
  line-height: 109px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(3) {
  height: 104px;
  line-height: 104px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(4) {
  height: 314px;
  line-height: 314px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(5) {
  height: 471px;
  line-height: 471px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(6) {
  height: 222px;
  line-height: 222px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(7) {
  height: 430px;
  line-height: 430px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(8) {
  height: 404px;
  line-height: 404px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(9) {
  height: 193px;
  line-height: 193px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(10) {
  height: 282px;
  line-height: 282px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(11) {
  height: 435px;
  line-height: 435px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(12) {
  height: 110px;
  line-height: 110px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(13) {
  height: 331px;
  line-height: 331px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(14) {
  height: 106px;
  line-height: 106px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(15) {
  height: 454px;
  line-height: 454px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(16) {
  height: 188px;
  line-height: 188px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(17) {
  height: 474px;
  line-height: 474px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(18) {
  height: 358px;
  line-height: 358px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(19) {
  height: 425px;
  line-height: 425px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(20) {
  height: 303px;
  line-height: 303px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(21) {
  height: 373px;
  line-height: 373px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(22) {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(23) {
  height: 423px;
  line-height: 423px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(24) {
  height: 228px;
  line-height: 228px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(25) {
  height: 257px;
  line-height: 257px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(26) {
  height: 108px;
  line-height: 108px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(27) {
  height: 302px;
  line-height: 302px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(28) {
  height: 345px;
  line-height: 345px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(29) {
  height: 332px;
  line-height: 332px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(30) {
  height: 295px;
  line-height: 295px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(31) {
  height: 308px;
  line-height: 308px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(32) {
  height: 338px;
  line-height: 338px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(33) {
  height: 441px;
  line-height: 441px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(34) {
  height: 131px;
  line-height: 131px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(35) {
  height: 166px;
  line-height: 166px;
}
.masonry-with-columns div:nth-child(36) {
  height: 382px;
  line-height: 382px;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry-with-columns">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div>
    2
  </div>
  <div>
    3
  </div>
  <div>
    4
  </div>
  <div>
    5
  </div>
  <div>
    6
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer fixes my problem but creates another https://jsfiddle.net/f6meq4rL/ - if you have more items they will not be align in a masonry way , thanks P. S. not sure how gave the downvote

Comment: @AndreiMaieras downvotes are given to *wrong* answers and you comment confirm this. I would ask *who gave the upvote?* ;)

Comment: I gave the upvote, not sure if it is a wrong answer, is just not the full answer, Is my mistake that I didn't give the full working example that I want

Comment: @TemaniAfif Based on the question and the given informations i made the best of it to show a working example wich it is. My Example (wich i also mentioned in the answer for people who like the downvotes) can be worked out further or the question can be updated with providing the whole code and more information about what responsive behavior is getting tried to achieve.